# Adjust the setting guides indentation to keep it to the UI guides of Flutter on the VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, editor, indentation

How can i set the guides indentation like this?

I just want to keep it to the Flutter UI Guides.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In Andriod Studio**

to enable flutter UI guides goto

`Files -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter`

and in editor enable(tick) the `Show UI guides for build methods`

**In VScode**

goto settings search for flutter UI and enable preview flutter UI guides

or

goto settings.json and add
`"dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true, "dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": true,` & restart the vscode

Comment: I mean the setting on the vs code. Not the Android Studio

Comment: in Vs code goto settings search for flutter UI and enable `preview flutter Ui guides`